# Как подключить примонтированную директорию через sshfs на другой машине

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, sshfs

Есть 3 тачки на ubuntu. На первой тачке создан пользователь и ограничен в правах так, что не может ходить дальше домашней своей директории.

Домашняя директория первой машины примонтирована в /media/user на второй тачке командой

```
echo 'password'| sshfs user@server-ip-address:/home/user /media/user -o password_stdin
```

На третей машине необходимо получить доступ к примонтированному каталогу /media/user второй машины.

При попытке выполнить ту же команду, система пишет что доступ запрещен. Экспериментировал с заданием пользователя root с выставлением прав 777 для всех созданых каталогов, но всё равно не удается получить доступ. Можно конечно было на прямую соеденить два сервера игнорируя промежуточное звено, но необходимо сделать всё же промежуточный сервер

Comment: от какого пользователя на второй тачке смонтирован каталог и под каким ты пытаешься смонтировать его на третьей? ЗЫ: вместо `echo 'password'` настрой аутентификацию по ключу...

Comment: 1-ая тачка. Создан юзер - admin. Выше домашней директории ходить не может. В домашней директории создана директория upload с полными правами для этого же юзера (admin)
2-ая тачка. Создан юзер - admin. В директории /media/ создана директория uploads. В нее с помощью команды которую я писал в вопросе, смонтирована директория upload с первой тачки
3-я тачка. При попытке смонтировать директорию /media/uploads со второго сервера под юзером admin той же командой, происходит следующее. В терминале request connection а в проводнике nemo получаю окно "Доступ запрещен"

Comment: Пользователь у тебя `admin`, а ты пытаешься подключиться и получить доступ к каталогу как `user`... отсюда и проблемы... либо всё делай от `admin`'а, либо укажи `-o allow_others` (см. `man sshfs`, есть нюансы с правами)